# Can't seem to load images in Django?

Tags: python, django, url, django-admin, django-models

This ought to be quite straight forward but I have a feeling one of the pathnames is screwing the whole thing up. Basically, my images are displaying as 404.

Here are the relevant parts to my Django app:

**models.py**

```
class MemeDetails(models.Model):
    datecreated = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    profileimage = models.ImageField(upload_to="memeimages", blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    origindate = models.DateField()
```

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/nai/Projects/meme/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

So all the images go into this folder `home/nai/Projects/meme/media/memeimages`

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
                 {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
```

**views.py**

```
def memepage(request, memeid):

    q = MemeDetails.objects.get(id=memeid)
    memeimage = q.profileimage

    return render_to_response('memepage.html', {'memeid': memeid, 'memeimage': memeimage},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**template**

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{memeimage }}" />, {{ memeid }}
```

The actual URL of the image is at this URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/memeimages/flickrphotobrowser.png` but I am getting a 404.

P.S I know I should use Apache to serve my static images on my production environment. I'm just trying to get this to work.

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` is probably also `/media/`. Change one of them.

Comment: Wow I have no idea how anyone (esp. a beginner) is supposed to know that.

Answer (score 0):

change the MEDIA_URL

MEDIA_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/'

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo. My MEDIA_URL is just `/media/`